# Имитация файла в потоке из строки

Tags: c#, потоки-данных

Может быть вы можете помочь или натолкнуть на правильное понимание вопроса.

Есть строка (обычный String), содержащая в себе json-образную инфу:
{"elemMain": 2, "Content": {"type": "general", "import": "False"}}"

Возможно ли её поместить в Stream (MemoryStream/FileStream/...) имитируя файл? Т.е. чтобы поток считал эту инфу файлом с конкретным названием (например, informer.json), но при этом сам файл на диске не создавался/не искался.

Comment: [StringReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.stringreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?

Comment: `Т.е. чтобы поток считал эту инфу файлом с конкретным названием` - поток не знает про названия файлов, он знает только про то, что есть место откуда можно считать\записать данные (если говорить про `Stream`)

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете записать вашу строку в MemoryStream и потом считать её оттуда. Вот пример

```
var str = "my awesome string";

using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    // Запишем строку в поток
    var bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str);
    stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

    // сдвинем позицию потока в начало
    stream.Position = 0;

    // далее можно работать с потоком
    var buffer = new byte[100];
    var bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    var strRead = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    Console.WriteLine(strRead);
}
```

Вывод

```
my awesome string
```